# Trying to figure out spamassassin globbing rules

Tags: spamassassin

How do the globbing rules work for spamassassin work? I've looked at the docs, but they are not clear as to whether sub-domains are included in a whitelist rule. For example, does:

whitelist_from *@somewhere.com

also whitelist addresses from subdomain.somewhere.com? This seems not to be the case, as subdomains are still labeled as spam, if they fail checking.

Should I use something like this:

whitelist_from *@*.somewhere.com

I've added this to some addresses to find out and it passes spamassassin --lint, but it may be a while before I get another email from one of those subdomain, so I thought I've just as here.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found the answer. I can use the whitelist_from_rcvd directive instead.